# What are natural alternatives to Nong Shim noodles?

Tags: noodles

My dad can't explain why he loves just  the Nong Shim noodles below. Are there more natural alternatives?

Note these  are NOT the instant cup noodles. He doesn't use their sauce that contains MSG.

[WordPress](https://sakiikas.wordpress.com/2011/09/22/potato-noodle-soup/)

[image: https://sakiikas.files.wordpress.com/2011/09/potato-noodle-contents.jpg]

[Blog spot](http://thenoodlefreak.blogspot.com/2010/03/review-nong-shim-shin-ramyun.html)
[image]
https://farm5.static.flickr.com/4010/4441115931_1d832d21e9_b.jpg

Comment: What property of these nodles do you want to avoid? "Healthy/unhealthy" are terms that don't mean the same to different people.

Comment: We can't deal with health issues or health claims on our site.  I'm afraid your question will likely be closed.

Comment: Sorry, but a generic “healthy” is off topic here. If you want to avoid a certain property, please [edit] your post accordingly and we can reopen. The [tour] and the [help], especially [ask], will explain more about how the site works

Comment: What do you mean by "natural"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Questions of health and nutrition are out of scope for this site. However, the question "what are alternatives to these instant noodles" is pretty straightforward.

[Instant noodles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instant_noodle) are typically preserved by flash-frying in oil. They arose as a quick-to-prepare and long-lasting alternative to fresh or frozen noodles. Thus, fresh or frozen noodles are a great replacement. Though they need to be refrigerated or frozen, and may require a longer cook time, they are typically made without oil.

In particular, both noodles in your question appear to be instant Korean ramyeon, which is very similar to Japanese ramen. In the United States, [Sun Noodle](http://sunnoodle.com/find-us/) produces fresh Ramen noodles that are commonly available at supermarkets or Asian grocers.